# Loki not sending alerts to alertmanager

Tags: linux, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-loki, promtail

Trying to setup a Promtail-Loki-Alertmanager log pipeline but Loki is not sending any alerts to AM. Each of those services are running in Docker containers.
Versions:

- Promtail: 2.8.2
- Loki: 2.8.2
- Alertmanager: 0.25.0

My line in test log file /var/log/script.log:
`[DEBUG] test debug alerting`

My Promtail config:

```yaml
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: "http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push"

scrape_configs:
- job_name: scriptlogs
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: scriptlogs
      severity: debug
      __path__: /var/log/script.log
```

My Loki config:

```yaml
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

common:
  path_prefix: /loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

ruler:
  storage:
    type: local
    local:
      directory: /loki/rules
  alertmanager_url: http://alertmanager:9093/api/v1/alerts
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  enable_api: true
  enable_alertmanager_v2: true
```

My Loki rule.yaml config (which path is /loki/rules/rule.yaml):

```yaml
groups:
  - name: debug-alert
    rules:
      - alert: DebugAlert
        expr: |
          {severity="debug"} == 1
        for: 1s
        labels:
          severity: debug
        annotations:
          summary: "Debug log alert"
          description: "A debug log entry was detected"
```

My Alertmanager config:

```yaml
---
route:
  group_by: ['severity']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5s
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: 'mattermost'
  routes:
  - receiver: 'mattermost'
receivers:
  - name: 'mattermost'
    webhook_configs:
      - url: 'http://mattermost:8065/plugins/alertmanager/api/webhook?token=MY_TOKEN'
```

What do I know so far?

-> Promtail can retrieve and parse the log file and
-> Loki receives the log with the correct label as I can search it in Grafana by using the label severity=debug

-> Alertmanager works and can receive alerts as it is receiving alerts from Prometheus without problem

So the issue really seems to be on the Loki end, either by the ruling config not being correct or has issues connecting to Alertmanager which I would doubt since I can poke the Alertmanager api from the Loki Docker container

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the config the same, but place the `rule.yaml` config file in `/loki/rules/fake/rule.yaml`.

It's not well documented, as shown [by this issue](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/5459), but if Loki is running in single tenant mode, the path will have `/fake/` appended as a folder, which is a reference to the Instance ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think your alert condition is wrong. If you want to query existing log records, you can use config as below:

```yaml
  - name: debug-alert
    rules:
      - alert: DebugAlert
        expr: count_over_time({severity="debug"}[1s]) > 0
        for: 1s
        labels:
          severity: debug
        annotations:
          summary: "Debug log alert"
          description: "A debug log entry was detected"
```